# CLEditor: add new button jquery plugin with Primefaces

Tags: jquery, primefaces, cleditor

I'm currently working on a project using `Primefaces` and I have defined a text editor using `p:editor`.

> ```
> <p:editor id="editorTexto" widgetVar="editorWidget" value="#{SomeBean.richText}" 
>     controls="bold italic underline strikethrough subscript rule cut copy paste print"/>
> ```

Now I need to add a fullscreen button and I found this solution: [CLEditor text editor on fullscreen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525448/cleditor-text-editor-on-fullscreen-mode)

The solution propouse to use a `jquery` plugin. I also saw others plugin's examples at http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/plugins.

But I'm facing problems on where and how I have to put the plugin's code on my project. It's on my `<head>` section? It's defining a new script using the statement $(document).ready?
I'm a novice on using `Primefaces` and `JQuery`.